# numpy matrix subset view

Tags: python, numpy

I want to view a numpy matrix by specifying the row and column number. For example, row 0 and 2 and column 0 and 2 of a 3×3 matrix.

```
M = np.array(range(9)).reshape((3,3))
M[:,[0,2]][[0,2],:]
```

But I know this is not a view, a new matrix is created due to the iterated indexing. Is it possible to do such a view?
I think it is strange that i can do

```
M[:2,:2]
```

to view the matrix. but not use

```
M[[0,1],[0,1]]
```

to achieve the same view.

EDIT: provide one more example. If I have a matrix

```
M = np.array(range(16)).reshape((4,4))
```

How do I get rows [1,2,3] and columns [0,2,3] with a single step of indexing? This will do it in 2 steps:

```
M[[1,2,3],:][:,[0,2,3]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### How do I get rows [1,2,3] and columns [0,2,3] with a single step of indexing?

You could use [np.ix_](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html#numpy.ix_) instead but this is neither less typing nor is it faster. In fact its slower:

```
%timeit M[np.ix_([1,2,3],[0,2,3])]
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.8 µs per loop

%timeit M[[1,2,3],:][:, [0,2,3]]
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.9 µs per loop
```

### How to force a view (if possible)?

You can use `numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` to ask for a tailored view of an array.
Here is an example of its use from [scipy-lectures](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/advanced/advanced_numpy/index.html#example-fake-dimensions-with-strides).

This would allow you to get a view instead of a copy in your very first example:

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

M = np.array(range(9)).reshape((3,3))
sub_1 = M[:,[0,2]][[0,2],:]
sub_2 = as_strided(M, shape=(2, 2), strides=(48,16))

print sub_1
print ''
print sub_2

[[0 2]
 [6 8]]

[[0 2]
 [6 8]]

# change the initial array
M[0,0] = -1

print sub_1
print ''
print sub_2

[[0 2]
 [6 8]]

[[-1  2]
 [ 6  8]]
```

As you can see `sub_2` is indeed a view since it reflects changes made to the initial array `M`.

The `strides` argument passed to `as_strided` specifies the **byte**-sizes to "walk" in each dimension:

The datatype of the initial array `M` is `numpy.int64` (on my machine) so an `int` is 8 bytes in memory. Since Numpy arranges arrays by default in `C-style` ([row-major order](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/glossary.html#term-row-major)), one row of `M` is consecutive in memory and takes 24 bytes. Since you want every other row you specify 48 bytes as stride in the first dimension. For the second dimension you want also every other element -- which now sit next to each other in memory -- so you specify 16 bytes as stride.

For your latter example Numpy is not able to return a view because the requested indices are to irregular to be described through `shape and strides`.

Comment: Indexing with ix_ is faster if you save the results of ix_ before timing.

Comment: @ggg, yes, either `meshgrid` or `ix_` consumes some time of function call.

Comment: Edit my earlier comment: Indexing with ix_ is faster *than double indexing* if you save the results of ix_ before timing.

Answer (score 1):

For your second example:

```py
import numpy as np
M = np.array(range(16)).reshape((4,4))
print(M[np.meshgrid([1,2,3],[0,2,3])].transpose())
```

the `.transpose()` is necessary because of `meshgrid`'s order of indexing. According to [Numpy doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) there is a new `indexing` option, so that `M[np.meshgrid([1,2,3],[0,2,3],indexing='ij')]` should work, but I don't have Numpy's latest version and can't test it.

Comment: I think indexing by ix_ is a better solution. meshgrid generates large matrices.

Answer (score 0):

`M[[0,1],[0,1]]` returns elements at (0,0) and (1,1) in the matrix.

Slicing a numpy array gives a view of the array, but your code `M[:2, :2]` gets a submatrix with row 0,1 and column 0,1 of `M`, you need `::2`:

```
In [1710]: M
Out[1710]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])

In [1711]: M[:2, :2]
Out[1711]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [3, 4]])

In [1712]: M[::2, ::2]
Out[1712]: 
array([[0, 2],
       [6, 8]])
```

Comment: ::2 only works in this specific example. I have added one more example to demonstrate my question.

Comment: @ggg, Theodros Zelleke has explained the best ;)

Answer (score 0):

To understand this behavior of numpy, you need to read up on numpy array striding. The great power of numpy lies in providing a uniform interface for the whole numpy/scipy ecosystem to grow around. That interface is the ndarray, which provides a simple yet general method for storing numerical data.

'Simple' and 'general' are value judgements of course, but a balance has been struck by settling on strided arrays to form this interface. Every numpy array has a set of strides that tells you how to find any given element in the array, as a simple inner product between strides and indices.

Of course one could imagine an alternative numpy which had different code paths for all kinds of other data representations; much in the same way as one could imagine the pyramids of Giza, except ten times bigger. Easy to imagine; but building it is a little more work.

What is however impossible to imagine, is indexing an array as arr[[2,0,1]], and representing that array as a strided view on the same piece of memory. arr[[1,0]] on the other hand could be represented as a view, but returning a view or copy depending on the content of the indices you are indexing with would mean a performance hit for what should be a simple operation; and it would make for rather funny semantics as well.